# autocompletion not working well on NetBeans for Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans, autocomplete

I'm using Netbeans 8 for Ruby development, I installed the plugins for Ruby development, from the community.
I'm working on a project, not on standalone files.
The problem that I'm facing, is: the **autocomplete** doesn't work all the time. Some methods don't appear in the list of autocomplete.
For instance if I type inside a class definition the beginning of a method like:
[image]

The only way to get the autocomplete working is to precede the method by it's class or object, like this:
[image]

I have also to say, that this problem occurs especially when I'm  inside a class  definition.
Do you have an idea, this autocompletion feature for Ruby isn't working well and how to fix it?

Comment: did you install netbeans plugins for ruby/ Ruby on Rails?

Comment: @Surya, yes I did. That's why the autocomplete is working in some contexts as I described above, without the plugins offered by the community at [link]http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38549/ruby-and-rails[link], the autocomplete will not work at all in any context.

Comment: @Amaynut not related but it only provides support for Rails 2.3.x. Why not use some text editor like sublime text or text mate? You also get to learn a lot when you use editor rather than some IDE

Comment: @Mandeep I tried sublime text 3, it's nice editor, very fast and clean. I even installed some plugins related to Ruby development, but the autocomplete feature is worse in sublime text. It loads only the words you typed on the current file and some file name, I think plus some words from the english dictionary. In some, it suggest a lot of things but the relevant methods and properties that I need for ruby development.